# Display "we will re-open tomorrow at ____" using PHP clock

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce

So I have a clock that I currently use to do many things throughout a Woocommerce shop. It functions perfectly and does its job.

I use 'open', 'closed' and 'last_call' to display messages in different areas of the site. It also disables certain things in the checkout depending on open status etc.

What I would like to do is use this function to display a "We will re-open again tomorrow at 9:00am" or, if close enough to open time, "We re-open at 9:00am (1 hour and 23 minutes from now)."

This is the code I have. Would I need to re-use this function and essentially duplicate much of it or is there a cleaner way of accomplishing this?

(PS. Store hours are pulled from an ACF date/time field in a custom Options page)

TIA

```
// -------------------------------------------
// STORE CLOCK
// -------------------------------------------
function store_clock() {

    $weekday_open = get_field('weekday_open', 'options');
    $sat_open = get_field('sat_open', 'options');
    $sun_open = get_field('sun_open', 'options');
    $weekday_close = get_field('weekday_close', 'options');
    $sat_close = get_field('sat_close', 'options');
    $sun_close = get_field('sun_close', 'options');
    $store_closed = get_field('close_store', 'options');

    $store_times = array(
        array( //Sunday
            'open' => $sun_open,
            'close' => $sun_close,
        ), 
        array( //Monday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Tuesday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Wednesday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Thursday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Friday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ),
        array( //Saturday
            'open' => $sat_open,
            'close' => $sat_close,
        ), 
    );

    $current_day = date( 'w', current_time('timestamp') ); //Numeric representation of the day (0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday)
    $current_date = date( 'd F Y', current_time('timestamp') );

    if ( $store_times[$current_day] !== false && $store_closed !== true ) {

        $opening_time = strtotime( sprintf( '%s %s', $current_date, $store_times[$current_day]['open'] ) );
        $closing_time = strtotime( sprintf( '%s %s', $current_date, $store_times[$current_day]['close'] ) );

        if ( $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') > 0 && $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') < 1800 ) {

            return 'last_call';

        } elseif  ( $opening_time > current_time('timestamp') || $closing_time < current_time('timestamp') ) {

            return 'closed';

        } else {

            return 'open';

        }
    } else {
        return 'closed';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reusing this piece of code to return an array, returning both the current status and the next days status. You may also want to take into account the date of the next opening for extended closing periods,

```php
// -------------------------------------------
// STORE CLOCK
// -------------------------------------------
function store_clock() {

    $weekday_open = get_field('weekday_open', 'options');
    $sat_open = get_field('sat_open', 'options');
    $sun_open = get_field('sun_open', 'options');
    $weekday_close = get_field('weekday_close', 'options');
    $sat_close = get_field('sat_close', 'options');
    $sun_close = get_field('sun_close', 'options');
    $store_closed = get_field('close_store', 'options');

    $store_times = array(
        array( //Sunday
            'open' => $sun_open,
            'close' => $sun_close,
        ), 
        array( //Monday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Tuesday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Wednesday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Thursday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ), 
        array( //Friday
            'open' => $weekday_open,
            'close' => $weekday_close,
        ),
        array( //Saturday
            'open' => $sat_open,
            'close' => $sat_close,
        ), 
    );

    $current_day = date( 'w', current_time('timestamp') ); //Numeric representation of the day (0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday)
    $current_date = date( 'd F Y', current_time('timestamp') );

    if ( $store_times[$current_day] !== false && $store_closed !== true ) {

        $opening_time = strtotime( sprintf( '%s %s', $current_date, $store_times[$current_day]['open'] ) );
        $closing_time = strtotime( sprintf( '%s %s', $current_date, $store_times[$current_day]['close'] ) );

        if ( $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') > 0 && $closing_time - current_time('timestamp') < 1800 ) {

            return array('last_call', null);

        } elseif  ( $opening_time > current_time('timestamp') || $closing_time < current_time('timestamp') ) {

            return array('closed', (isset($store_times[$current_day + 1]) ? $store_times[$current_day + 1]['open'] : $store_times[0]['open']));

        } else {

            return array('open', null);

        }
    } else {
        return array('closed', (isset($store_times[$current_day + 1]) ? $store_times[$current_day + 1]['open'] : $store_times[0]['open']));
    }
}
```